# How to call a method of another class in some class using SyncFusion Blazor to refresh a component?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, syncfusion

I have the following problem:

When my menu sidebar changes from "open-state" to "closed-state", or other way around, the width of the components in the page are not refreshed and that result in something like this:

[image]

Now this can be solved with calling the "Refresh" function of the SfMaps component so the width is refreshed aswell, however I'm unable to do that because my Sidebar is in another Razor component.

Therefore I need a solution in my NavMenu.razor(sidebar component) that will call a method in another class that refreshes the SfMap component, this method will be called from the OnChange method of the sidebar.

This is What I've tried so far:

Declare the instance of the Test.page and call the "RefreshItem()" method when the state of the sidebar has changed:

NavMenu. razor:

```
<SfSidebar Width="250px"
       EnableDock="true"
       DockSize="65px"
       Position="SidebarPosition.Left"
       Type="SidebarType.Push"
       @ref="Sidebar"
       IsOpen="true"
       Changed="ManageSideBar">
</SfSideBar>

@code{

 [CascadingParameter]
 ApplicationName.Pages.Test testLayout { get; set; } 

 void ManageSideBar()
 {
    if (testpage != null)
    {
        this.testLayout.RefreshItem();
    }
}
}
```

Test.Razor:

```
<SfMaps ID="map" @ref="maps" Width="100%">
        
</SfMaps>

@code
{
   SfMaps maps;

  public void RefreshItem()
  {
      maps.Refresh();
  }
}
```

However this code does not work somehow, its telling me that "Test.Razor" is null even after I loaded it.
Does someone know how this happends or does anyone have another solution how to tackle my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared a simple sample to achieve your expected requirement. In the below sample, we have used a time delay on the click method where the sidebar is expanded/collapsed. This is because the sidebar is collapsed before the page component is resized completely. The Refresh() method of Maps is called before that. So the maps component is refreshed after the component is resized completely using the time delay.

Sample link -  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/292460/ze/BlazorApp1906858485

Refer the below links for Maps and Sidebar component.

Maps:

UG documentation- https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/maps/getting-started/

Demo link- https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/maps/default-functionalities

API reference- https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Maps.SfMaps.html

Sidebar:

UG documentation- https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/sidebar/getting-started/

Demo link- https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/sidebar/default-functionalities?theme=bootstrap4

API reference- https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.SfSidebar.html

Please let us know, if you need any further assistance.

Regards,
Sowmiya.P